A morphism of double complexes induces a qis on total complexes under certain hypotheses. Proof involving a spectral sequence
$\def\Tot{\operatorname{Tot}}
\def\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}}$I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 0133 of the Stacks Project. Note that hypotheses (3) and (4) can be restated by saying: extend the complex $K^\bullet$ to a double complex $K^{\bullet,\bullet}$, where $K^{p,0}=K^p$, $K^{p,q}=0$ if $q\neq 0$ and the horizontal differential $d_1^{p,q}$ of $K^{\bullet,\bullet}$ is $d_1^{p,0}=d^p_{K^\bullet}$. Then: (3') the maps $\alpha^p$ assemble into a morphism of double complexes $\alpha^{\bullet,\bullet}:K^{\bullet,\bullet}\to A^{\bullet,\bullet}$ as $\alpha^{p,0}=\alpha^p$, and (4') $\alpha^{p,\bullet}:K^{p,\bullet}\to A^{p,\bullet}$ is a quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes, for each $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. The lemma then asserts that (1)+(2)+(3')+(4') implies that $\Tot(\alpha^{\bullet,\bullet}):K^\bullet=\Tot(K^{\bullet,\bullet})\to\Tot(A^{\bullet,\bullet})$ is a quasi-isomorphism.
I understand everything from the proof except the second-to-last sentence: “Hence we conclude that $H^n(\operatorname{Tot}(A^{\bullet,\bullet}))=H^n(K^{\bullet})$.” On the one hand, we have that $H^n(K^\bullet)={}'E_2^{p,0}={}'E_\infty^{p,0}$, since the spectral sequence degenerates on the second page. On the other hand, according to Definition 012U, we have that ${}'E_\infty^{p,0}$ equals
$$
\label{frac}\tag{1}
\frac{F^p_IH^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet}))}{F^{p+1}_IH^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet}))}
$$
(where $F_I$ is this filtration).
Since $A^{\bullet,\bullet}$ is concentrated in the first and second quadrants, we get $F_I^{p+1}\Tot^p (A^{\bullet,\bullet})=0$ (the filtration $F_I$ in the total complex is given at the beginning of Section 012X). Thus the denominator in \eqref{frac} vanishes. Putting all together, we have
$$
H^n(K^\bullet)=F^p_IH^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet})).
$$
Why should it be $F^p_IH^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet}))=H^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet}))$? In general we only have
$$
F^p_IH^p(\Tot (A^{\bullet,\bullet}))=\frac{\Ker d^p_{\Tot(A^{\bullet,\bullet})}\cap F^p\Tot^p(A^{\bullet,\bullet})+\operatorname{Im}d^{p-1}_{\Tot(A^{\bullet,\bullet})}}{\operatorname{Im}d^{p-1}_{\Tot(A^{\bullet,\bullet})}}.
$$

It seems that 0133 is a particular case of the more general Theorem 12.5.4 in Kashiwara, Schapira, Categories and Sheaves. Moreover, the proof of the latter does not require spectral sequences.

You seem to be opposed to spectral sequences and I don't understand why--they are a standard tool for these types of computations.
The result follows from remembering that $E_\infty^{p,q} = 0$ for $q \neq 0$. Thus the filtration on $H^*(\mathrm{Tot}(A^{\bullet,\bullet}))$ is concentrated in one degree.

Ahh, that was indeed what I was missing. Thanks! I have nothing against spectral sequences haha. It's just that it is the first time that I am dealing with them.
